# Convert meters to feet to inches c++?

Tags: c++

I can't figure out how to get the inches, it only works for the feet not the inches

Here is the part of the code which should convert meters to feet to inches

An example of the output should be:

Enter a number of meters as a double: 15

The value of 15.00 meters is 49 feet and **2.55** inches.

```
//

//METERS_PER_FOOT=0.3048

//INCHES_PER_FOOT=12.0

//makes conversion from metric to English units

void convert(int& feet, double& inches, double meters)

{

  feet=meters/METERS_PER_FOOT;

  inches=feet/INCHES_PER_FOOT; //this line should give me inches

}
```

Comment: Please show your cout statement. My guess is that you should remove "" from inches in your cout statement. Also, I think you should multiply by INCHES_PER_FOOT, not divide.

Comment: You can just convert directly. temp = 39.37007874016 * meters 
After converting to inches use the mod to get the inches then use temp - inches to get feet.

Comment: Also, why are the definitions of `METERS_PER_FOOT` and `INCHES_PER_FOOT` commented out? And isn't one of them inverted in your calculation? You're using `meters / METERS_PER_FOOT` to go from meters to feet, but then using `feet / INCHES_PER_FOOT` to go from feet to inches. Shouldn't it be `FEET_PER_INCH` in the second one? (Or multiply by `INCHES_PER_FOOT` instead of dividing?)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic maths

Answer (score 2):

You need to multiply instead of divide.

There are 12 inches / foot. Dividing feet by inches / foot gives you feet^2 / inches, which is kind of weird.

You code should read

```
inches=feet*INCHES_PER_FOOT;
```

Notice that you have (meters)/(meters/foot) but have (foot)/(inches/foot), which is why one works but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to convert meters to feet and meters to inches then
use

```
feet=meters/METER_PER_FOOT;
inches=feet*INCHES_PER_FOOT; this will convert feet to inches
```

If you just want to represent meters in terms of feet and inches
use

```
feet=floor(meters/METER_PER_FOOT);
inches=floor(meters/INCHES_PER_METER)-feet*INCHES_PER_FOOT;
cout << meters << "Meters=" << feet<<"feet"<<inches<<"inches";
```

Answer (score 0):

For the future, try to have all of them of the same type for you might lose some value when relying on the automatic type conversion.